# How to filter the elements in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario, in that I have to filter the elements in dropdown based on input given in text box. Is it possible, so how to do that? I tried with ng-change but it is not getting.

Html code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="somvar" ng-change="someFunc(somvar)" />

<div id="dropdown" class="dropdownClass">
    <ul class="predtsct">
        <li class="prfdwn" ng-repeat="list in countries| filter: somevar" ng-click="countryIdFunc(countriesLst.countryId)">{{list.countryName}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: had this fiddle lying around: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/r74aK/ is it what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jorg no i need dropdown,I got with ul's,but need to filter in dropdown based on inputbox

Comment: The dropdown is just styling. Where is the searchbox?

Comment: @Jorg  can you please check the question I updated it.

Comment: A dropdown is just styling on the `<ul>`. I added default bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/6gvp2z9h/

Comment: @Jorg thanq so much it's worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fiddle I posted in the comments: A dropdown works no differently that an ordinary list, except that the styling is different. This example uses Bootstrap to do the dropdown, but you can find many other examples if you google them.

Working version: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/6gvp2z9h/

This is the entire view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  city: <input type="text" ng-model="search.city">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <!-- the 'search' bit in the filter maps to the 'search' variable on $scope -->
      <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search:strict">{{user.name}}, {{user.city}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The controller is also pretty small:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.search = {};
  $scope.search.city = 'new york';
  $scope.users = [{
    name: 'bob',
    city: 'hong kong'
  }, {
    name: 'jack',
    city: 'new york'
  }, {
    name: 'john',
    city: 'new hampshire'
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) it provides very flexible control of drop-down lists and filtering of it.

Comment: you can customize this with your css, or you will need to handle text change event of the input field with some timeout for example.

Comment: I used ng-change,it is working fine for input box and div witg list items,but not with dropdown.

Comment: @bpbsr I think Jorg's comment is the answer you are looking for, I have forgotten about filter in angular JS